# Memory allocation using array

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

Can someone please tell me, what in general, will the following do in C ?

```
H.L = new int* [H.n];
```

Does this command create L variable in structure H of integer type with size n?

Comment: Please also post the definition of the `struct`s. Without that, nothing exact can be said. However, `new` is used to allocate dynamic memory and return the address of the first index element of the allocation, which can be then be stored in a pointer and then accessed through it.

Comment: It won't compile in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create an array of `H.n` pointers to `int`. A pointer to the first array element will be stored in `H.L`.

If you wanted an array of `int`s, remove the asterisk.

On a side note, you may be happier using a `vector<int*>` instead.

It is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the right side of the expression statement

```
H.L = new int* [H.n];
```

there is created an array of type `int *[H.n]` using unary operator `new []`. That is each element of the array has type `int *`.

Expression `H.n` used in square brackets specifies the number of elements of the allocated array and must be converted to type `size_t`. Usually it is some integral type as for example `int`.

According to the C+ Standard (5.3.4 New)

> 1. ...If it is an array, the new-expression returns a pointer to the initial
>      element of the array.

So the left side lvalue `H.L` should have type `int **` or some type (usually in rare cases) that can be converted from `int **`.